# Overcoming an n^2 runtime program

Tags: c++, c++11, types, absolute-value

Is there a way to overcome a nested loop recursion in C++11? My program has a slow runtime. Or rather, is there a more efficient way to solve for the following formula `z=|a-b|*|x-y|`,with a, b, x and y being elements in a 10000 integer array?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

ifstream in("int.in");

int main()
{
    long long n, n1, z, x, y, in2=0;
    in>>n
    long long l[n], p[n];
    for(x=0;x!=n;x++)
        in>>l[x]>>p[x];
    for(x=0;x!=n;x++)
    {
        for(y=x+1;y<n;y++)
        {
            ineq+=(abs(l[x]-l[y])*abs(p[x]-p[y]))); //executes slow
            /*n1=l[x]-l[y]; //Alternative algorithm
            if(n1<0)
                n1*=-1;
            z=p[x]-p[y];
            if(z<0)
                z*=-1;
            in2+=n1*z;*/
        }
    }
    cout<<in2<<"\n";
}
```

I tried to change the data types to `short int`,  `long`, `long long` and `unsigned`, but it either dumps garbage values or executes ``Segmentation Core Fault` errors.

For the absolute value formula, I originally tried using a hard-coded approach (commented out), but it seemingly outputs garbage values. I've also tried to optimize the abs solution with the `abs()` function `ineq+=abs(l[x]-l[y])*abs(p[x]-p[y]));`, but it seems to execute slower. I do not know of any other optimizations I can implement, so please do recommend some.

Linux-friendly solution preferred. Thank you.

Side Note: the values of a, b, x and y are all within the range `1<=a,b,x,y<=10000`.

Side Note: this program reads from a file "int.in", takes the first integer (the number of items) and reads each new line by pair (l[x] and p[x] are pairs).

Side Note: I also tried using only a multidimensional array, but I   read somewhere that a one dimension array is in the CPU cache, while multidimensions are scattered in the memory and is slower.

Comment: Can you explain why you are computing this? Then it might be easier to suggest an alternative algorithm.

Comment: Related, what are you trying to accomplish in the big picture? For example, I think Fourier Transforms run in `n log n`, so if you can move it to the FFT domain, you will get your speedup.

Comment: And z can be whatever? You want to have **all** the solutions or just one?

Comment: `|a-b|*|x-y|` is exactly the same to `z=|(a-b)(x-y)|`. That saves you an absolute call

Comment: your alternative way is no better than the other one because `n1*=-1;` will be costlier than `n1 = -n1;` if the compiler is not smart enough, and the `if` may incur a branch while `abs` will use the most eifficient way to take absolute

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I know I'm stepping boundaries here, but readability is not a necessity in this program, as a separate program will simply redirect the compiled .exe's stdin and stdout to a file (which is not the point of this program; its just to automate things) and thus I only require the fastest possible code with the smallest possible space on memory. in both cases, abs() failed.

Comment: I didn't talk about readability here but performance. A multiplication is obviously much slower than a negation. And 2 `abs` calls obviously are slower than a single call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be drawn in another way: you're looking for c and d (*both positive*) in the equation `z=c*d` (of course `c is |a-b|` and `d is |x-y|`).

So first order your arrays. Then look for solution of `z=c*d` then find which a and b make `c == a - b` true and x and y that make `d == x - y` true.

Once it's done you've got all the values that makes your equation true since abs(a-b) is the same as abs(b-a)